# Why is the NSTextAlignment enum defined differently for TARGET_OS_IPHONE?

Tags: ios, uikit

I was just looking at NSText.h in UIKit and the following bit of code caught my eye as being unusual

```
/* Values for NSTextAlignment */
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, NSTextAlignment) {
    NSTextAlignmentLeft      = 0,    // Visually left aligned
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    NSTextAlignmentCenter    = 1,    // Visually centered
    NSTextAlignmentRight     = 2,    // Visually right aligned
#else /* !TARGET_OS_IPHONE */
    NSTextAlignmentRight     = 1,    // Visually right aligned
    NSTextAlignmentCenter    = 2,    // Visually centered
#endif
    NSTextAlignmentJustified = 3,    // Fully-justified. The last line in a paragraph is natural-aligned.
    NSTextAlignmentNatural   = 4,    // Indicates the default alignment for script
} NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

Why have the values for NSTextAlignmentRight and NSTextAlignmentCenter been flipped for TARGET_OS_IPHONE vs not?

Answer (score 2):

Prior to iOS 6, iOS didn't have `NSTextAlignment`. iOS used `UITextAlignment`. And the `Center` value was `1` and the `Right` value was `2`.

Then in iOS 6, `NSTextAlignment` was added. To keep backward compatibility, `NSTextAlignmentCenter` was given the same value as `UITextAlignmentCenter`. Same for `Right`.

It was more important that the `NSTextAlignment` enum on iOS matched up with the deprecated `UITextAlignment` than it was to be the same as the value from OS X.

The original difference between `UITextAlignment` on iOS and `NSTextAlignment` on OS X was probably a simple oversight. But that's a simple guess.